# Bound Principle for Integer Linear Programming and Linear Programming

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, approximation

Currently, I am learning approximation algorithms. When I learned Vertex Cover via LP, I encountered a principle called Bounding Principles.
It like this:

(1) The maximum value for an ILP problem is always less than or equal to the maximum 
value for the LP relaxation:

MAX for ILP ≤ MAX for LP relaxation

(2) The minimum value for an ILP problem is always greater than or equal to the 
minimum for the LP relaxation:

MIN for ILP ≥ MIN for LP relaxation

I cannot figure out why "MAX for ILP ≤ MAX for LP relaxation" and "MIN for ILP ≥ MIN for LP relaxation".

Can anyone explain, thx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ILP has an extra constraint than LP problem. The constraint is that all variables should be integers.

Hence, the optimal solution for an ILP shall be at best as good as an optimal solution for an LP problem, it can never be better.